# Send Email using rules or other module depending on a field value?

Tags: 7, hooks, rules

What I'm trying to do is when a user creates a node on content type "Sample" with the field "Priority" set to "High" that said user will receive an email notification containing the field values of the node and a link.

I tried using rules but I can't seem to find a condition that supports a field containing value. I'm thinking into creating a hook function when the user creates a node. But the problem is I'm very new to drupal and I still don't know where to start. Can anyone enlighten me on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to expose the node's field using the condition "entity has field" as the very first condition. Then Rules will allow you to select the field in the condition "data comparison".

Comment: This. It's likely that your rule isn't completely sure which content type it's interacting with, so it wont offer you fields specific to that content type, only generic info it knows about all nodes (author, NID, date created etc)